# Contour Plot of a set of equations?

Tags: plotting

For the set of equations the set of equations, w versus A has to be plotted, I have written the code but can't seem to figure out where I'm wrong, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Clear[c, m, e, c1, cp, M, F, Fp, A1, B1, A1p, B1p, bet, alp, betp, \
alp, w, wpp]
m = 0.08
e = 0.4
Mum=0.08
Rm=1
c1 = 0.02
w =.
A =.
wpp =.
k1 = 1000
k2 = 700
lep = 3*(k1/(M + m))^0.5
M = 1
c = c1/(M + m)
const1 - 4*funct2
alp = k1/(M + m)
bet = k2/(M + m)
F = m*e*w^2/(M + m)
wpp = w/alp^0.5
cp = c/(alp)^0.5
betp = bet*A^2/alp
Fp = F/(alp*A)
A1p = A1/A
B1p = B1/A
eqn = {-cp*wpp/3 + 3*betp*B1p/4 == 0, 
      ((1 - wpp^2)*B1p + (3*betp*B1p/4)*(2 + A1p^2 + B1p^2) - 
      cp*wpp*A1p)^2 + ((1 - wpp^2)*A1p + (betp/4)*(1 + 6*A1p + 3*A1p^3 + 
      3*A1p*B1p^2)+cp*wpp*B1p)^2 == Fp^2, 
      (1 - wpp^2/9) + (3*betp/4)*(1 + A1p + 2*A1p^2 + 2*B1p^2) ==0,
      Mum*Vs/Rm - Mum^2*w/Rm == c*(A^2*w^2/18 + Ah^2*w^2/2),
      ((alp - w^2)*Ah + 3/4*bet*Ah^3)^2 + c^2*Ah^2*w^2 == (F*w^2)^2
      };
ContourPlot[eqn, {Vs,0,15},{w}]
```

Comment: B1 can be found out in terms of A from -cp*wpp/3 + 3*betp*B1p/4 == 
0 and A1 can be found out from ((1 - wpp^2)*B1p + (3*betp*B1p/4)*(2 + A1p^2 + B1p^2) - 
    cp*wpp*A1p)^2 + ((1 - wpp^2)*
     A1p + (betp/4)*(1 + 6*A1p + 3*A1p^3 + 3*A1p*B1p^2) + 
    cp*wpp*B1p)^2 == 
Fp^2 in terms of A, basically reducing the whole set into a relation between A and w and plotting for {w,90,95} particularly where the subharmonic amplitude exists.

Comment: edit the question with new info. Its too hard to read code in comments.

Comment: Edited, Please have a look.

Comment: You have significantly changed the equations in the question.  You now have eight unknowns and five equations.  What do you want plotted against what?

Comment: @bbgodfrey The first three equations in eqn give a relationship between A and w,The fourth is a relation between Vs,A and Ah, the final one is a relation between Ah and w, the plot is for Vs and w. for {Vs,0,15}

Comment: The five equations contain the following  unknowns, `{A, A1, Ah, B1, Mum, Rm, Vs, w}`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I'm sorry, the values of Mum and Rm are added.

Comment: What is the range of `w` to be plotted?

Comment: {w,20,100}, the range of w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system of equations `eqn` (less the second equation) is equivalent to a 24th order polynomial, so eliminating variables `{A, A1, Ah, B1}` symbolically does not seem practical.  Instead, eliminate those variables numerically, proceeding as follows.  First, `Rationalize` all decimal numbers (perhaps unnecessary here but usually a good practice).  Then define a new variable `f` as the `Real` numerical mismatch between the left and right sides of the second equation.  It is this quantity that will be used in `ContourPlot`.

```
eqnr = Rationalize@eqn;
eqnf = Join[eqnr, {f ∈ Reals}]; eqnf[[2]] = f == Subtract @@ eqnr[[2]]
```

and actually evaluate `f` by means of

```
ff[Vs0_?NumericQ, w0_?NumericQ] := 
    Min[f /. NSolve[eqnf /. {Vs -> Vs0, w -> w0}, {A, A1, Ah, B1, f}]]
```

which solves for `f` numerically, and returns the smallest value, if any.  A typical plot of `ff` for constant `Vs` is

```
Plot[ff[1., x], {x, 9, 12}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-.02, .2}}, PlotPoints -> 10]
```

[image]

It shows three roots, the second of which can be traced as a function of `Vs` in a few minutes.

```
opts = {AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> Infinity}
start = {x /. Quiet@FindRoot[ff[1, x], {x, 9.7, 9, 10}, Evaluate@opts], 
         x /. Quiet@FindRoot[ff[1.1, x], {x, 9.9, 9, 10}, Evaluate@opts]};
Do[tem = 2 start[[i - 1]] - start[[i - 2]];
    new = x /. Quiet@FindRoot[ff[1. + (i - 1)/10, x], {x, tem, tem - 0.3, tem + .3}, 
    Evaluate@opts]; If[NumericQ[new], AppendTo[start, new], Break[]], {i, 3, 141}]
p1 = ListLinePlot[start, DataRange -> {1, 1 + (Length@start - 1)/10}]
```

[image]

Finally, the requested `ContourPlot` can be computed, although slowly, by

```
Table[{y, x, ff[y, x]}, {y, 1, 15, .02}, {x, 9, 14, .02}];
p2 = ListContourPlot[Flatten[%, 1], Contours -> {10^-3}, ContourShading -> None,  
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

The "zero" contour has been chosen as slightly larger than zero, because the value of `ff` never quite reach zero, because of the finite precision of the original equations in the question as well as the finite resolution of `ListContourPlot`.  Even with this chose of contour value, the curves are broken in places.

Answer (score 3):

here is a start, make all your floats rationals (eg, `m=8/100`) and note the first equation is linear in `B1`, so eliminate to obtain two equations in `A,A1,w`:

```
 eqn = Simplify[(eqn /. First@Solve[eqn[[1]], B1])[[2 ;;]]]
```

[image]

`ContourPlot3D` can handle this:

```
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[eqn], {w, 0, 150}, {A, -2, 2}, {A1, -4, 4}, 
 PlotPoints -> 10]
```

[image]

the intersection of those surfaces is your solution ( so at least we know there is a solution.

Now you can play the same game and eliminate `A1` , the last equation is quadratic so you get two solutions:

```
  {v1, v2} = eqn[[1]] /. Solve[eqn[[2]], A1];
```

unfortunately this doesn't work..probably because the function produces many complex values near the zero solution

```
  ContourPlot[v1, {w, 100, 120}, {A, -2, 2}]
```

looking at the real part:

```
g = Evaluate[v1[[1]] - v2[[2]]];
ContourPlot[Re[g] == 0, {w, 0, 150}, {A, -2, 2}, Contours -> {0}]
```

[image]

may be your solution..

Comment: Can I get some help to go into further equations plotting for Vs vs w, there are a couple of more equations but I want to figure them out myself. Thanks.